# Visual Studio Team Services downloaded code with wrong encoding

Tags: encoding, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services. My code contains word in Hebrew.
I build the code with one computer and now I am working on another computer.
When I worked on the first computer every thing was fine.
When I downloaded the code to the second computer the Hebrew word turn to be gibberish. If I look on the code online, he is fine.
what can I do to solve it?

Thanks,
Ditza

Comment: go to below link if it is helpfull for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654096/how-to-deserialize-and-serialize-build-process-parameters-in-tfs

Comment: I can't see how it connect

Answer (score 0):

Go To Team menu in visual studio and then go to "Connect to team project" option and set the path for tfs and connect thought that.