# Accessing to the build process parameters in the Pre-Build script

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild, build-definition

How can I access to my Build Process parameters into the Pre-Build / Post-Build script. I cannot pass it in argument because I need to prompt the user to ask him the version number before queuing this Build.
I have try with $env:MyVariableName but it is empty.

Comment: Can you better articulate "I cannot pass it in argument because I need to prompt the user to ask him the version number before queuing this Build" ?

Answer (score 0):

If when he queues the build, he can provide the version number, that version number can become an input parameter in the process template that is then passed as a parameter to the powershell activity that then passes it to your script, which can then be accessed via Param($version).

But, if you still need to directly access the build definition process parameters, you need use C# and the TFS API as with this:

[How to Deserialize and Serialize Build Process Parameters in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654096/how-to-deserialize-and-serialize-build-process-parameters-in-tfs)